# Angular, Swagger: Right way to create new Object of interface

Tags: angular, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am working with the following, generated, typescript interface:

```
export interface GlassesInput {
  metadata: GlassesInputMetadata;

  localizations: Array<GlassesInputLocalizations>;
}
```

Retrieving data via the generated Service is no problem anymore, so my next goal is to actually create data on the frontend and 'push' it to the backend.

Since I know interfaces can only be implemented and not instantiated, how do I go about actually creating an instance of said interface.

I've seen things like `let v = {one: 'one', two: 'two'}` which implys that all needed data is available at instantiation time, which is not possible for my case.

to clarify what I'd like:

```
private g: GlassesInput = new GlassesInput();
```

What is the right way to go in angular/typescript?

Comment: Could you go `let v = {one: null, two: null}` and then update the object with subsequent data when it becomes available?

Comment: @jcroll The goal is to have html-inputs to provide the data, since I have no idea how html-inputs work, I have no idea if your way is possible

Comment: Create smaller objects, of smaller classes/interfaces, and combine/transform them when you have all the needed information.